# How to perform range updates in sqrt{n} time?

Tags: algorithm, optimization, query-optimization, square-root

I have an array and I have to perform query and updates on it.
For queries, I have to find frequency of a particular number in a range from l to r and for update, I have to add x from some range l to r.

How to perform this?

I thought of sqrt{n} optimization but I don't know how to perform range updates with this time complexity.

**Edit** - Since some people are asking for an example, here is one

Suppose the array is of size n = 8

and it is

1 3 3 4 5 1 2 3

And there are 3 queries to help everybody explain about what I am trying to say

Here they are

q 1 5 3 - This means that you have to find the frequency of 3 in range 1 to 5 which is 2 as 3 appears on 2nd and 3rd position.

second is update query and it goes like this - u 2 4 6 -> This means that you have to add 6 in the array from range 2 to 4. So the new array will become

1 9 9 10 5 1 2 3

And the last query is again the same as first one which will now return 0 as there is no 3 in the array from position 1 to 5 now.

I believe things must be more clear now. :)

Comment: Google "Square Root Decomposition"

Comment: Tried it @shole. Didn't work. Can you please attach any link if you know about one?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking for. Provide some examples. Also, are you really trying to do this in an array, or are you allowed to use some other data structure, so long as you can perform those queries that you described?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because we are not here to do your homework.

Comment: @YvesDaoust..Please have a look again. I have updated the question and I apologise for doing anything wrong. This is the first time I am using stackoverflow.

Comment: @JimMischel..Have a look again Please. I have updated the question.

We are trying to do this in an array only but we can obviously use any other data structure for solving it.

Comment: What you are looking for is segment tree. This question can be reduced to range sum query. Which again uses the above mentioned data structure. This https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZBHKZF5w4YU video should help yuo implement this

Comment: @thebenman I know about segment tree and lazy propagation. I am confused about how I can find the frequency after each update.

Answer (score 0):

I developed this algorithm long time (20+ years) ago for Arithmetic coder.
Both Update and Retrieve are performed in O(log(N)).

I named this algorithm "Method of Intervals". Let I show you the example.

Imagine, we have 8 intervals, with numbers 0-7:

```
+--0--+--1--+--2-+--3--+--4--+--5--+--6--+--7--+
```

Lets we create additional set of intervals, each spawns pair of original ones:

```
+----01-----+----23----+----45-----+----67-----+
```

Thereafter, we'll create the extra one layer of intervals, spawn pairs of 2nd:

```
+---------0123---------+---------4567----------+
```

And at last, we create single interval, covers all 8:

```
+------------------01234567--------------------+
```

As you see, in this structure, to retrieve right border of the interval [5], you needed just add together length of intervals [0123] + [45]. to retrieve left border of the interval [5], you needed sum of length the intervals [0123] + [4] (left border for 5 is right border for 4).
Of course, left border of the interval [0] is always = 0.

When you'll watch this proposed structure carefully, you will see, the odd elements in the each layers aren't needed. I say, you do not needed elements 1, 3, 5, 7, 23, 67, 4567, since these elements aren't used, during Retrieval or Update.

Lets we remove the odd elements and make following remuneration:

```
+--1--+--x--+--3-+--x--+--5--+--x--+--7--+--x--+
+-----2-----+-----x----+-----6-----+-----x-----+
+-----------4----------+-----------x-----------+
+----------------------8-----------------------+
```

As you see, with this remuneration, used the numbers [1-8]. Lets they will be array indexes. So, you see, there is used memory O(N).

To retrieve right border of the interval [7], you needed add length of the values with indexes 4,6,7. To update length of the interval [7], you needed add difference to all 3 of these values. As result, both Retrieval and Update are performed for Log(N) time.

Now is needed algorithm, how by the original interval number compute set of indexes in this data structure. For instance - how to convert:

```
1 -> 1
2 -> 2
3 -> 3,2
... 
7 -> 7,6,4
```

This is easy, if we will see binary representation for these numbers:

```
1   -> 1
10  -> 10
11  -> 11,10
111 -> 111,110,100
```

As you see, in the each chain - next value is previous value, where rightmost "1" changed to "0". Using simple bit operation "x & (x - 1)", we can wtite a simple loop to iterate array indexes, related to the interval number:

```
int interval = 7;
do {
  int index = interval;
  do_something(index);
} while(interval &= interval - 1);
```

Comment: Sounds like Fenwick tree!

Comment: Thanks for reference, I did not know about his algorithm and structure. Yes, very similar to my one. I developed this in 1996, so Fenwick has "scientific priority" on this idea.